# Regex not matching when input string contains an ampersand

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex that starts with a letter followed by only  letters, spaces, commas, dots, ampersands, apostrophes and hyphens.

However, the ampersand character is giving me headaches.  Whenever it appears in the input string, the regex no longer matches.

I am using the regex in an ASP.net project using C# in the 'Format' property of a `TextInput` (a custom control created in the project).  In it, I am using `Regex.IsMatch(Text, Format)` to match it.

For example, using this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&.,'\- ]*$
```

The results are:

```
John' william-david                      Pass
John, william'david     allen--tony-''   Pass
John, william&david                      Fail
```

Whenever I put a `&` in the input string the regex no longer matches, but without it everything works fine.

How can I fix my issue?  Why would the ampersand be causing a problem?

Notes:

- I've tried to escape the ampersand with `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\&.,'\- ]*$` but it has the same issue
- I've tried to put the ampersand at the beginning or end o `^[a-zA-Z][&a-zA-Z.,'\- ]*$` or `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.,'\-\& ]*$` but it also doesn't work

Comment: Where are you using this regex? With `grep`?

Comment: Your expression works fine ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE8rC6/1)).

Comment: If you are using this from the command line with `grep`, make sure you put it in quotes. `&` is a special character in Bash and so it needs to be escaped or in quotes.

Comment: i am putting it in as the 'Format' property of a textbox, and in code behind, i am using Regex.IsMatch(Text, Format) to match it, code is c#

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thx, wired, i am trying at the W3school website http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_test, it's returning as false whenever i have & in it

Comment: There, you may try using `&amp;`. In c#, `&` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere else. The following expression evaluates to `true`:

```
Regex.IsMatch(@"John, william&david", @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&.,'\- ]*$")
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDvQNP

Comment: thx, i was trying that regex in the W3school website here, http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_test, the regex actually works in code, my bad, i should ve tried in code first

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the comments that your problem pertains to C#, so I'll answer your question in that context.  If ampersand (`&`) is truly giving you issues in your character class, you should specify it in an alternate manner.
Luckily, C# supports [hex escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which means that you can specifying `&` as `\x26`.

For example, instead of:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z&.,'\- ]*$
```

use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\x26.,'\- ]*$
```

If that doesn't fix your issue, then your issue is not the `&`, it's something else.