# Regex not matching against ampersand

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the following regex:

```
\b(?:mr|mrs|ms|miss|messrs|mmes|dr|prof|rev|sr|jr|&|and)\.?\b
```

In other words, a word boundary followed by any of the strings above (optionally followed by a period character) followed by a word boundary.

I'm trying to match this in Java, but the ampersand will not match. For example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "\\b(?:mr|mrs|ms|miss|messrs|mmes|dr|prof|rev|sr|jr|&|and)\\.?\\b", 
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    
String result = p.matcher("mr one and mrs.two and three & four").replaceAll(" ");
    
System.out.println("["+result+"]");
```

The output of this is: `[  one    two   three & four]`

I've also tried this at regex101, and again the ampersand does not match: https://regex101.com/r/klkmwl/1

Escaping the ampersand does not make a difference, and I've tried using the hex escape sequence `\x26` instead of ampersand (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534822/regex-not-matching-when-input-string-contains-an-ampersand)). Why is this not matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex *will* match an ampersand if it is located in between word chars, e.g. `three&four`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/26HiMv/1). This happens because `\b` before a non-word char requires a word char to appear immediately before it. Also, as there is a `\b` after an optional dot, both the dot and ampersand will only match if there is a word char immediately on the left.

You need to re-write the pattern so that the word boundaries are applied to the words rather than symbols:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:\\b(?:mr|mrs|ms|miss|messrs|mmes|dr|prof|rev|sr|jr|and)\\b|&)\\.?", 
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/klkmwl/2).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is due to use of word boundaries. There are no word boundaries before or after a non-word character like `&`.

In place of word boundary you can use lookarounds:

```sh
(?<!\w)(?:[jsdm]r|mr?s|miss|messrs|mmes|prof|re|&|and)\.?(?!\w)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/klkmwl/4)

- `(?<!\w)`: Make sure that previous character is not a word character
- `(?!\w)`: Make sure that next character is not a word character

Note some tweaks in your regex to make it shorter.